# How does the charAt() method work with taking numbers from strings and putting them into new strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, ascii, charat

```
public String getIDdigits()
    {
        String idDigits = IDnum.charAt(0) + IDnum.charAt(IDnum.length() - 1) + "";
        return idDigits;
    }
```

In this simple method, where IDnum is a 13 digit string consisting of numbers and is a class variable, the given output is never what I expect. For an ID number such as 1234567891234, I would expect to see 14 in the output, but The output is always a three-digit number such as 101. No matter what ID number I use, it always is a 3 digit number starting with 10. I thought the use of empty quotation marks would avoid the issue of taking the Ascii values, but I seem to still be going wrong. Please can someone explain how charAt() works in this sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are taking a `char` type from a `String` and then using the `+` operator, which in this case behaves by adding the ASCII numerical values together.

For example, taking the char `'1'`, and then the char `'4'` in your code

```
IDnum.charAt(0) + IDnum.charAt(IDnum.length() - 1)
```

The compiler is interpreting this as its ASCII decimal equivalents and adding those

```
49 + 52 = 101
```

Thats where your 3 digit number comes from.

Eradicate this with converting them back to string before concatenating them...

```
String.valueOf(<char>);
```

or

```
"" + IDnum.charAt(0) + IDnum.charAt(IDnum.length() - 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```java
public String getIDdigits()
    {
        String idDigits = "" + IDnum.charAt(0) + IDnum.charAt(IDnum.length() - 1);
        return idDigits;
    }
```

When you first adding a empty it's add `char` like `String` if you put it in end it first add in number mode(ASCII) and then convert will converts that to `String`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to be more explicit about the string concatenation and so solve your statement like this :

```java
String idDigits = "" + IDnum.charAt(0) + IDnum.charAt(IDnum.length() - 1);
```

The result of adding Java chars, shorts, or bytes is an int: